# Chrome Package App - Webview for Mobile

Tags: google-chrome, webview

I developed a chrome packaged app and was successful running it on a computer (Windows, Mac, Linux). Basically what the app does is it refers to another web application that I created as well with Google Maps Javascript API in it that displays the location using pushpins and I am displaying it using webview.

However, we need this app to be ported to a mobile device as well but when I tested on my Samsung Tablet with android version 4.4.2, the webview does NOT seem to work even if I enabled the "webview":"system" in the Manifest.mobile.json. Is there a way for me to achieve this in porting the chrome app to mobile using webview?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I have already read from the API and Libraries page of mobile chrome app under "APIs Coming in the Long Term" section in where webview is listed and so  tag is not supported "yet".

https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/blob/master/docs/APIsAndLibraries.md